# Batch to count lines in files in subdirectories gives wrong results

Tags: batch-file

In a batch file I want to count lines in files in a few directories and use the line count in an environment variable later in that batch. For example, consider I have the following files:

```
Directory1\update.log       (1 line)
Directory2\update.log       (2 lines)
Directory3\update.log       (3 lines)
```

This is the batch file I'm using:

```
for /d %%d in (*.*) do (
   echo Processing %%d
   cd %%d
   for /f %%c in ('find /v /c "" ^< update.log') do set count=%%c
   echo Count is %count%
   cd ..
)
```

Now I open a new command window and call that batch. The results of the first call are:

```
Processing Directory1
Count is
Processing Directory2
Count is
Processing Directory3
Count is
```

And any subsequent call in the same command window results in

```
Processing Directory1
Count is 3
Processing Directory2
Count is 3
Processing Directory3
Count is 3
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't have time to write up the full answer, but look up "delayed expansion".  Short version you need to enable that, then use ! instead of % inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment of @RyanBemrose I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file) which lead me to the following working code:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /d %%d in (*.*) do (
   echo Processing %%d
   cd %%d
   for /f %%c in ('find /v /c "" ^< update.log') do set count=%%c
   echo Count is !count!
   cd ..
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that *cmd* expands `%count%` *as it reads the loop*. This leads cmd to execute the following loop:

```
echo Processing %d
cd %d
for /f %c in ('find /v /c "" ^< update.log') do set count=%c
echo Count is
cd ..
```

If you are not into delayed expansion, another trick is to quote `%count%` with extra `%`s, and then to force expansion of that *during execution of the loop* will a `call`.

```
for /d %%d in (*.*) do (
    echo Processing %%d
    cd %%d
    for /f %%c in ('find /v /c "" ^< update.log') do set count=%%c
    call echo Count is %%count%%
    cd ..
)
```

Ugh (for *cmd* in general).