# How can I reuse environment variables in Windows?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, java-home

I used to use like this.

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\...
Path=...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

And I want to use two separated variables for `JAVA_HOME` and tried this.

```
JAVA7_HOME=C:\...
JAVA8_HOME=C:\...
JAVA_HOME=%JAVA8_HOME%
Path=...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

And it seems not work. The actual value of `Path` just contains `%JAVA8_HOME%`.

```
C:\Users\whoami\>echo %Path%
...;%JAVA8_HOME%\bin;...

C:\Users\whoami\>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Take a look here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file

Comment: I assume you're defining these in the control panel environment variable dialog. The assignment order of `REG_EXPAND_SZ` variables (i.e. the value has at least two `%` symbols) is undefined since the enumeration order of values in a registry key is undefined. Thus a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` variable such as `Path` should depend directly on only simple `REG_SZ` variables such as `JAVA7_HOME`.

Answer (score 1):

`SET` [Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html). Changes made with `SET` will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.

```
set "JAVA7_HOME=C:\..."
set "JAVA8_HOME=C:\..."
set "JAVA_HOME=%JAVA8_HOME%"
set "Path=%Path%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
```

**Note** `"` double quotes in all `SET "variable=string"`: used to ensure there are no unwanted spaces in variable *name* or string *value*.

> Any extra spaces around either the variable name or the string will
>   not be ignored. `SET` is not forgiving of extra spaces like many other
>   scripting languages.

**Note** `PATH` [Display or set a search path for executable files](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html). Hence, instead of

```
set "Path=%Path%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
```

you could use simply

```
Path=%Path%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```