# Batch Getting & Displaying User Input

Tags: batch-file, output, echo, user-input

Why is this code not working?

```
@echo off
set /p param=Enter Parameters: 
echo %param%
```

Output:

```
(Nothing)
```

I have searched all relative posts, but I can't find what is wrong with it.  There is no space problem, or syntax problem that I can identify

**Update:**
As **rojo** stated, since the code block is working, here is the full code, which is not working.

```
@echo off

for /f %%j in ("java.exe") do (
    set JAVA_HOME=%%~dp$PATH:j
)

if %JAVA_HOME%.==. (
    echo java.exe not found
) else (
    set /p param=Enter Parameters: 
    echo %param%
    (statement using JAVA_HOME)
)

pause
```

Output:

```
Enter Parameters: jfdklsaj
ECHO is off.
...
```

Comment: Unable to recreate.  There's nothing wrong with that code.  Must be something wrong with where you're putting it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Example of delayed expansion in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file)

Comment: I don't really understand why, but it works, so I will put this as a solution.

Comment: @gagarwal I suggest you remove your question, there's already lots of questions on SO that are answered by the delayed expansion, I don't believe we need another one. I'm glad the link could help you though.

Comment: @Laf I get your point, but beginners may find this useful, like my self, who didn't know what delayed expansion was.  I. Will remove it in a month if it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Laf** indicated, this can be fixed with delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%j in ("java.exe") do (
set JAVA_HOME=%%~dp$PATH:j
)

if %JAVA_HOME%.==. (
    echo java.exe not found
) else (
    set /p param=Enter Parameters: 
    echo !param!
    (statement using JAVA_HOME)
)
```