# How to use array index in batch scripts?

Tags: arrays, batch-file

i want set varable instead index of array in loop (batch script)
like:

```
@ECHO OFF

set array[1]=22750289 512
set array[2]=22750289 5600
set array[3]=22750289 5612

for %%N in (1,1,3) do (
    echo %array[%%i]%
    echo %array[1]%
 )
```

but result :
 ECHO is off.
 22750289 512
 ECHO is off.
 22750289 512
 ECHO is off.
 22750289 512

Comment: You may read a full description on array management in batch files at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need to enable delayed variable expansion using `setlocal`:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set array[1]=22750289 512
set array[2]=22750289 5600
set array[3]=22750289 5612

for /L %%N in (1,1,3) do (
echo !array[%%N]!)

endlocal
```

Notice that the variables are no longer available after `endlocal`.

For more information about delayed variable expansion reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/5047996).

Comment: Also worth nothing that you're going to want to use a `for /L` loop instead of the regular `for` loop you've got there.