# Batch scripting GPG decryption

Tags: batch-file, gnupg

I'm trying to write a Batch file to decrypt a folder of `.gpg` files that have all been encrypted with the same public key. This is what I have so far:

```
@ECHO off
SET outbound=C:\encrypted files
SET olddir=%CD%
SET password=correcthorsebatterystaple
CD /d %outbound%
DIR *.gpg /B > tmp.txt
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN (tmp.txt) DO (
    ECHO %%F > tmplen.txt
    FOR %%L IN (tmplen.txt) DO (SET namelen=%%~zL)
    DEL tmplen.txt
    gpg --output %%F:~0, namelen-4 --batch --yes --passphrase %password% --decrypt %%F)
DEL tmp.txt
CD /d %olddir%
```

Currently it just prints

```
usage: gpg [options] [filename]
```

This is my first time trying to write a Batch script, so I'm sure it's something simple.

Comment: `namelen` looks wrong. You set it repeatedly, and never use it. You could need `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and `set /a namelen=!namelen!-4` and `gpg --output %%F:~0, !namelen!` to do what it looks like you're trying to do.

Comment: According to another answer I found, that should give me the length of the string %%L, though I notice now that I have a typo there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
@ECHO off
SET password=correcthorsebatterystaple
PUSHD "C:\encrypted files"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('DIR *.gpg /B') DO (
    gpg --output %%~nF --batch --yes --passphrase %password% --decrypt %%F)
POPD
```

Explanation:

- `PUSHD` and `POPD` are used to temporarily manoeuvre into another directory;
- there is no temporary text file required to hold the output of `DIR`, because `FOR` is also capable of parsing the output of a command (the set within `IN ()` is enclosed with `''` so it is interpreted as a command, not a file spec.);
- to truncate the file extension (what you want to do with the second temporary file and the inner `FOR` loop, at least according to my interpretation), you just need to give the modifier `~n`, in our situation `%%~nF`; your method did not work because:

  - you cannot do in-line maths like you tried by `namelen-4` (you would need to use an interim variable together with `SET /A` for arithmetic operations, and also [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10558316/5047996) had to be active then);
  - the substring expansion like `:~0,8` does not work with `FOR` variables (you would need an interim variable to do that, and again [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10558316/5047996) had to be active then);

Addition:
If the script has problems with whitespaces in the input file names, you may need to exchange the `gpg` command line with this:

```
gpg --output "%%~nF" --batch --yes --passphrase %password% --decrypt "%%~F"
```

The `~` modifiers remove potential surrounding double-quotes, so `"%%~nF"` and `"%%~F"` always enclose the file name with double-quotes. Notice that `"%%F"` could lead to double-double-quotes unintentionally...

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome. I've never done any Batch scripting before, so this is really cool to see.

Comment: // , How could I do this in a way that relies on the Gnu Privacy Guard Key Ring already having the Private Key decrypted and Cached in Memory?

Comment: Sorry, @NathanBasanese, I can't help you with this; I just answered this question because it was a pure [tag:batch-file] issue; I don't know any details about `gpg`...