# Batch scripting not assigning variable as expected

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a batch script which will assign a variable string and then trim it. I'm facing two issues:

1. The variables are not assigning properly. It is taking last value from from the variable file.
2. The variables are not assigning the first time I run the script. I need to run the script second time to see if the variables have been assigned. On third run, I can see the trim is working.

My script looks like this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr "W3SVCWINSRVRHOSTS" "C:\Data\SiebelAdmin\Commands\file.txt"') do (
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ("%%a") do (
for %%c in (%%b) do (
echo in loop
set str=%%c
echo %%c
echo.%str%
set str=%str:~-6%
echo.%str%
)))
```

The output looks like this on third run:

> ```
> > C:\Users\parthod\Desktop>b.bat
> in loop
> xsj-uvapoms72
> 7.2.27
> 7.2.27
> in loop
> xsj-uvapoms82
> 7.2.27
> 7.2.27
> in loop
> 172.17.2.26
> 7.2.27
> 7.2.27
> in loop
> 172.17.2.27
> 7.2.27
> 7.2.27
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You fell into the [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/5047996) trap -- try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr "W3SVCWINSRVRHOSTS" "C:\Data\SiebelAdmin\Commands\file.txt"') do (
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ("%%a") do (
for %%c in (%%b) do (
echo in loop
set str=%%c
echo %%c
echo.!str!
set str=!str:~-6!
echo.!str!
)))
endlocal & set str=%str%
```

In between the `setlocal`/`endlocal` block, delayed variable expansion is active. To actually use this feature enclose the variables by `!!` rather than `%%`.
Since `setlocal` sets up a new namespace for variables, the compound `endlocal & set` statement is required to transfer the value of `str` beyond the block.

Comment: The key point is the "!" instead of "%"; I was struggling with this but your explanation sets it clear.