# How to escape percent `%` sign in the body of `forfiles`?

Tags: for-loop, cmd, escaping

I am using `forfiles /S` to iterate over a directory tree. I'm running it directly in the **command prompt**.
To find out the current directory I want to expand the built-in variable `%CD%`, but not immediately (showing the current directory of the command prompt instance that executes `forfiles`), but with `%` escaped in a way that `%CD%` is expanded by the command prompt instance in the body of `forfiles`.

```
forfiles /S /P "D:\Data" /M "*.txt" /C "cmd /C echo %CD%"
```

Is there a way to escape `%` and so to kind of hide it from the main command interpreter instance?
I tried `%%` (that works fine within a batch file), `^%`, `\%`, and even enclosing `%CD%` in plain and escaped quotes (`"%CD%"`/`\"%CD%\"`), but I had no success so far.

I know I could use [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/5047996) like the following, but I want to avoid it:

```
forfiles /S /P "D:\Data" /M "*.txt" /C "cmd /V:ON /C echo !CD!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From command line, if you don't escape the percent sign, the variable is directly replaced with its value, but if you escape it (with a caret),

```
forfiles /S /P "D:\Data" /M "*.txt" /C "cmd /C echo ^%CD^%"
```

as the command is enclosed in quotes (`forfiles` requirement in your command) the carets are not removed and the literal `%cd%` (there are carets escaping the percent signs) is echoed for each file.

The simplest solution is not to escape the percent signs, but use the special character management in `forfiles` command, replacing the problematic `%` with its ASCII code value

```
forfiles /S /P "D:\Data" /M "*.txt" /C "cmd /C echo 0x25cd0x25"
```

Or, you can define the command inside a variable and then use it

```
set myCommand=cmd /c echo ^%cd^%
forfiles /S /P "D:\Data" /M "*.txt" /C "%myCommand%"
```

Comment: Thank you! If I get it right, the second work-around using a variable is not limited to `forfiles`, it may also be used for other commands that take quoted strings.