# echo variable is not working in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

My batch file execution throws error at echo echo %outfvar%. The following is the batch file I wrote:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a incvar = 1
set outfvar = "outfile"_!incvar!".res"
echo !outfvar!
echo *.txt > !outfvar!
set /a incvar = incvar+1

FOR %%pat in (%*) do(
    FOR /F %%k in (!outfvar!) DO( grep -l !pat! !k! >>outfile_!incvar!.res)
    set /a incvar = incvar+1
    set outfvar = "outfile"_!incvar!.res
                     )
```

Error is "%pat was unexpected at this time.."
Can anybody help me to execute this batch file successfully?

Comment: it's actually not a good idea to edit the question so that the solutions from the answer(s) are implemented; imagine other users viewing the post...; a better way is to provide an answer wher you present your solution...

Comment: I've rolled back the changes to the question - @Smij01 the aim is to accept an answer that solves your question - using the green tick when it becomes available, (see the help tour).  You can ask another question to solve a different problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the spaces around `=` in *all* `set` commands.

There must be a space in between `do` and `(` in the line of `for`.

The line

```
set outfvar = "outfile"_%incvar%".res"
```

should read

```
set "outfvar=outfile_%incvar%.res"
```

(The quotes as you stated them were part of the string value.)

`for` variables *must* consist of *one* letter only and need to be expanded by preceding with `%%`. You are trying to use `%%pat` in your code, which will not work. State `%%p` instead (also inner `for`).

Finally, you need **delayed expansion** to be able to read variables you modify within the same (compound) command, the `for` in your code. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/5047996) to learn how it works.

Comment: also needs delayed expansion

Comment: @aschipfl: I have removed the spaces around = and added space between do and ( as you have instructed. now I am getting another error : %pat was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @aschipfl: I have changed using delayed expansion. But still I am getting "%pat was unexpected at this time."

Comment: You are trying to use `%%pat` as a variable of `for` -- as I mentioned in my answer... by the way, you should insert a space in between `do` and `(` at both `for` lines...

Comment: So how should I correct it? I am new to batch programs, so don't mind if my doubt seems so silly.