# batch file exit automatically after typing "

Tags: batch-file

I have created a batch file as below

```
@echo off
echo  Type Below Requirements:
echo.
:username
set /p usr= Type Username:
if %usr%==[%1]==[] goto username
echo Your username is: %usr%
pause
```

This is working perfectly when I am typing any text, but if I type " batch is Exit Automatically.

Comment: What do you want the `if %usr%==[%1]==[] ` line to do??

Comment: If some one didn't type any thing it should repeat the question again, for that purpose I have if %usr%==[%1]==[] correct me if I am wrong. thanks

Comment: Oh Thanks for that, and if you can please guide me through this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the comparison expression syntax `if %usr%==[%1]==[]` is wrong, it should read `if [%usr%]==[]` instead.

Secondly, to handle double-quotes correctly, you will need to enable [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/5047996).

The following should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo  Type Below Requirements:
echo.
:username
set usr=
set /p usr= Type Username:
if [!usr!]==[] goto username
echo Your username is: !usr!
pause
```

Comment: Is it Possible to restrict by typing space and symbols, ex: "test username" and "test@username" should not allowed...

Comment: In above batch file,Is it Possible to give a alert, ex: You Input username in invalid if type "space or symbol", and for the password it should match password Policy...

Comment: Yes: a good starting point for that is string replacement expansion like `%usr:@=%` (see `set /?` for help); compare it with `%usr%` using `if`; if the strings do not equal, one or more `@` are present...

Comment: If  you can Please Show me a sample code, I did not get what you explained to me... Thanks,

Comment: For example, you want to check whether the value of `%usr%` contains any spaces, you could do this: `if "%usr: =%"=="%usr%" echo No spaces encountered.`; the first expansion uses string replacement (see `set /?` for details) where spaces are replaced by nothing, so if there are spaces, the comparison fails;

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way:

```
@echo off
echo  Type Below Requirements:
echo.
:username
set "usr="
set /p "usr= Type Username: "
if not defined usr goto :username
echo Your username is: %usr%
pause
```