# only keeping the last 30 lines in a text file using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hello I have a log file that I am creating and updating every hour, 
it runs a lot of files therefore it fills up very quickly.

What I want to do is to purge every once in a while only leaving the last 30 lines of the file.

I have been trying to do this for a while I know there is the "More" command that can print the lines from the n line. What I want is to use that command or something similar but instead of printing it I want it to write to a file.

This is what I got so far.

```
set LINES=0
for /f "delims==" %%I in (test2.txt) do (
    set /a LINES=LINES+1
)
@echo   
set /a LINES=LINES-30
more +%LINES% < test2.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using some simple Logical tricks:

```
for /f %%i in ('type test2.txt^|find /c /v ""') do set /a lines=%%i-30
if %lines% leq 0 goto :eof
more +%lines% test2.txt>test2.tmp
move /y test2.tmp test2.txt
```

(this counts also empty lines; Pauls approach ignores them. What's better, depends on your needs)

Comment: @Stephan Nice solution, I didn't know that I could set the number in that way without incrementing:  `set /a lines=%%i-30` +1 and as favorite to remember.

Comment: Great approach (+1), for not ignoring empty lines!

Comment: Congratulations all on your success reinventing the `tail` command.

Comment: @Paul Thanks ^^ You can make it complete with minor changes:  `...('type "%~1"...` and `...do  set /a lines=%%i - %2` and saving it as "tail.bat"

Comment: Is there a way to do `tail -f`?

Comment: @Stephan - The -f switch does a "follow" on the file. It will continue to output lines as they are added to the file. You might use this to watch the end of a web server log file or anything else that is long running and adds lines to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a simpler solution but here's one that just me immediately in mind.

```dos
@echo off

rem creating env testing
(
    for /l %%i in (1,1,50) do (
        echo %%i. What I want to do is to purge every once in a while only leaving the last 30 lines of the file.
    )
)>%TEMP%\_file.tmp

rem Script start here.
set lines=0
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%TEMP%\_file.tmp) do set /a lines+=1

if %lines% LEQ 30 echo nothing todo &exit /b 0

set /a lines=lines-30
set "_skip=skip=%lines%"

set count=0
for /f "%_skip% delims=" %%i in (%TEMP%\_file.tmp) do (
        echo %%i
        set /a count+=1
)
echo found %count% lines
exit /b 0
```

The trick here is to count the number of line and subtract 30 then you get the number of lines you have to skip.

This is how could be for your need.

```dos
@echo off

set lines=0
for /f "delims=" %%i in (test2.txt) do set /a lines+=1

if %lines% LEQ 30 echo nothing todo &exit /b 0

set /a lines=lines-30
set "_skip=skip=%lines%"

(for /f "%_skip% delims=" %%i in (test2.txt) do (
        echo %%i
))>%TEMP%\_file.tmp
move /Y %TEMP%\_file.tmp test2.txt
exit /b 0
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, it does not work for me though when i run it it prints in cmd window 30 times the line  What I want to do is to purge every once in a while only leaving the last 30 lines of the file.
and it doesn't update the file test2.txt i see you created and used some sort of temp file but i am not sure how to use that.
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Although [@Stephan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32756986/5047996) might be the best approach, I still want to contribute an answer, which relies on the code of the question...

Here is a corrected version of the original code:

```
@echo off
set LINES=0
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%I in (test2.txt) do (
    set /A "LINES=!LINES!+1"
)
endlocal & set /A "LINES=%LINES%-30"
if %LINES% GEQ 0 more +%LINES% test2.txt
```

There were two issues:

1. reading variables like `LINES` in `set /A` is more or less equivalent to `%LINES%`, but you need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/5047996) and explicit `!LINES!` expansion here;
2. there was a `=` too much at the `delims=` option (you do not want to specify `=` as delimiter);

However, two issues remain using the `for /F` implementation:

1. empty lines are not taken into account by `for /F`, so such are not counted;
2. lines beginning with `;` are ignored too, because of the default `eol=` option;

---

#### Update

You can avoid [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/5047996) if you adapt the syntax of `set /A` a bit, and you can overcome the issues concerning empty lines and lines starting with `;`:

```
@echo off
set /A "LINES=0"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('
    findstr /N /R "^" "test2.txt"
') do (
    set /A "LINES+=1"
)
set /A "LINES-=30"
if %LINES% GEQ 0 more +%LINES% "test2.txt"
```

Comment: `set /a` don't really need the `%` or `!`. `set /a lines+=1` works fine even in a block.

Comment: @Stephan, in this special case, you're right, of course; but I was thinking about that in general...

Comment: thanks for the help. i am still a bit new to batch scripting so this are good pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tail.bat` that can be used like the traditional `tail` command. No, still no `-fqv` capabilities.

```
@SETLOCAL
@SET EXITCODE=0

@SET /A LINES=10

@IF "%1" EQU "" (
    @ECHO. usage: %0 [-n] filename^(s^)
    @ECHO.
    @ECHO. example: %0 -3 thefile.txt
    @SET EXITCODE=1
    @GOTO :EOF
)

@SET LC=%1
@IF "%LC:~0,1%" EQU "-" (
    @SET /A LINES=%LC:-=%
    @SHIFT
)

@SET FILENAME=%~1
@IF NOT EXIST "%FILENAME%" (
    @ECHO. The file "%FILENAME%" does not exist.
    @SET EXITCODE=2
    @GOTO TheEnd
)

@FOR /F %%i IN ('TYPE "%FILENAME%" ^| FIND /C /V ""') DO @SET /A NLINES=%%i-%LINES%

@IF %NLINES% LEQ 0 (
    @TYPE "%FILENAME%
) ELSE (
    @MORE +%NLINES% "%FILENAME%"
)

:TheEnd
@EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the machine / OS has PowerShell available then:

```
@echo off    
PowerShell.exe -Command "(Get-Content \".\test2.txt\" -Tail 30) | Set-Content  \".\test2.txt\""
```

The performance hit from this will likely be far lower, the other batch methods are dependant on reading and counting the lines in batch-land - not always that good an idea.

Comment: I get an error when I run this command: 
https://i.imgur.com/yCQpnWi.png

Comment: @Frak If you're already inside the PowerShell (instead of inside a batch file) you just run the PowerShell command: 
`Get-Content ".\test2.txt" -Tail 30 > test2.txt`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that too and although the Tail command works, the redirect to overwrite the existing file doesn't. test2.txt ends up being an empty file.

Comment: @Frak You might try one of the other methods of PowerShell outputting to file found here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/how-to-send-output-to-a-file/

Comment: I know how to output to a new file. I am saying that overwriting the same input file method does not work. I have tried the other commands too.  If you are pointing to other methods, then are you acknowledging that your answer is incorrect and does not work. Have you actually tested it?

Comment: @Frak I don't know I tested it back in 2016, I usually do... however I've updated the answer with a fix to support overwriting the same file as input file.

Comment: Good man! Thank you. I just tested it and it worked. This was the one-line answer I was looking for.