# In Windows batch - how do I replace single quote with escape single quote to feed SQL

Tags: sql, windows, batch-file, escaping, quote

With my Windows batch file, I have following SQL statement:

```
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6* delims=, " %a in (myfile.txt) do(
    sqlcmd -SmYSerbver  -Uhhh -P12345 -dmyDB_Admin -Q"insert into tableA (UserID,FirstName,LastName,Email,DisplayName,OrgUnit,LoadDate) values('%%a','%%b','%%c','%%d','%%e','%%f',getdate())"
)
```

One user's last name is "O'Brien" - my variable %%c is evaluated as O'Brien.

How do I operate to make  %%c evaluated as "O''Brien"?

Comment: Provide more code, please; where do all the `%%` variables come from??

Comment: I used: following string replacement and it does not work:
set %%b=%%%b:'=''%
  set %%a=%%%a:'=''%
  set %%f=%%%f:'=''%
  set %%c=%%%c:'=''%
  set %%d=%%%d:'=''%

Comment: You cannot apply the string replacement syntax `%VAR:str=rpl%` to `for` variables, you'll need an interim "normal" variable, but with delayed expansion due to `for`... and insert a space in between `do` and `(`...

Comment: ...and it must read `for /F %%a` (not `%a`)...

Comment: This is the first time I write window batch. Could you show me a couple of lines of sample codes?

Comment: I just summarised all that in an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32982411/5047996)...

Comment: Are you sure that you actually want a QUOTE character in the last name string rather than an APOSTROPHE? I do not know anyone named `O"Brien`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an interim variable to do string replacements as the related syntax cannot be applied to `for` variables like `%%c` directly. For this to work, [delayed variable expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/5047996) needs to be enabled, and the interim variable needs to be expanded using `!!` rather than `%%`.

The following illustrates how to accomplish that for the value in `%%c`, using the interim variable `c_tmp`:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6* delims=, " %%a in (myfile.txt) do (
    set "c_tmp=%%c" & set "c_tmp=!c_tmp:'=''!"
    sqlcmd -SmYSerbver  -Uhhh -P12345 -dmyDB_Admin -Q"insert into tableA (UserID,FirstName,LastName,Email,DisplayName,OrgUnit,LoadDate) values('%%a','%%b','!c_tmp!','%%d','%%e','%%f',getdate())"
)
endlocal
```

When `%%c` contains a string `O'Brien`, `c_tmp` will finally contain `O''Brien`.

Of course you can do also other replacements by modifying the command `set "c_tmp=!c_tmp:'=''!"` accordingly.

Comment: I replaced with 2 single quotes and it works:

set "c_tmp=%%c" & set "c_tmp=!c_tmp:'=''!"

Comment: Ah, apparently I misread `''` as `"`... anyway, you got the idea how it works and fidured it out yourself... so I adapted my answer to comply with that...

Comment: I would like to do the same escaping, but my input is a environment variable, not a file. I have ```set "Name=O'Brien"``` so if i do ```echo %Name%``` the output is ```O'Brien```. How do I define a SafeName variable so that if i do ```echo %SafeName%``` the output is ```O''Brien``` (that is the content of Name but with each apostrophe replaced by two apostrophes)? --- EDIT: Apparently it's as simple as ```set "Safename=%Name:'=''%"```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could escape single quote with `\` like `O\'brian` if it's sqlcmd failing to insert.

If the file containing single quotes that does not use for delimitation of values, then you could replace all occurrences in an intermediate file.

```
(
echo O'Brian1a, O'Brian1b, O'Brian1c, O'Brian1d, O'Brian1e, O'Brian1f
echo O'Brian2a, O'Brian2b, O'Brian2c, O'Brian2d, O'Brian2e, O'Brian2f
echo O'Brian3a, O'Brian3b, O'Brian3c, O'Brian3d, O'Brian3e, O'Brian3f
)>%tmp%\myfile.tmp

( 
  for /f "delims=" %%i in (%tmp%\myfile.tmp) do (
    set "i=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo !i:'=\'!
  )
)>%tmp%\int-myfile.tmp

for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=, " %%a in (%tmp%\int-myfile.tmp) do ( 
  echo '%%a','%%b','%%c','%%d','%%e','%%f'
)
```

output:

```
'O\'Brian1a','O\'Brian1b','O\'Brian1c','O\'Brian1d','O\'Brian1e','O\'Brian1f'
'O\'Brian2a','O\'Brian2b','O\'Brian2c','O\'Brian2d','O\'Brian2e','O\'Brian2f'
'O\'Brian3a','O\'Brian3b','O\'Brian3c','O\'Brian3d','O\'Brian3e','O\'Brian3f'
```

As a last resort you can always choose with which character you replace in the line: `echo !i:'=\'!`