# how to compare numeric variables in batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

why doesn't this work?

```
SET FIRST=""
SET COUNT=0
FOR %%F IN (dir *.png) DO (
  IF %COUNT% NEQ 0 GOTO _skip
  SET FIRST=%%F
:_skip
  ECHO "%%F",
  SET /A COUNT=COUNT+1
)
```

It sets `FIRST` to the last `*.png` because the `IF` condition fails, because `COUNT` - although is incremented by `set /A`, the `IF %COUNT%` doesn't ever work.  Very frustrating.

Comment: 1. you are not really working with **DOS**, are you (`set /A` was not supported back then!)? 2. you'll need [delayed variable expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/5047996) as you modify and read `COUNT` within the `for` loop; 3. do *not* use `goto` within code blocks like `for` since they break the block context;

Comment: In general, it would be very helpful if you described what "not working" means and what you expected your code to do...

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to count, just do `goto skip` after echo line.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b *.png') do (
  rem :: you can use "echo %%f" instead of "set first=%%f"
  set first=%%f
  goto _skip
)
:_skip
echo %first%
```

you mixing two things to scan folder.

Here is the second way:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.png) do (
  set first=%%f
  goto _skip
)
:_skip
echo %first%
exit /b 0
```

---

If you need absolutely to count, here is the way to skip with count. As stated in comment, you need to enable `delayedExpansion`

```
@echo off

set count=1
for %%f in (*.png) do (
  set first=%%f
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  if "!count!"=="1" goto _skip
  endlocal
  set /a count+=1
)
:_skip
echo !first!
```

Comment: why did you place `setlocal` in the `for` body? why not stating it once before `for`?

Comment: @aschipfl because filename with "!" I put expansion where is needed. I don't remember which post explain this

Comment: Okay, good point! however, you need `endlocal` then *before* `set /a` to disable the delayed expansion for the next `for` loop iteration...