# batch script for file system: use of for-loop variable in another nested for-loop

Tags: variables, batch-file, for-loop, nested

the last 4-5 hours I spent trying to get my script fixed, and tried several things, but it still doesn't work as supposed. Here is the working part:

```
    @echo off
    rem automatically sort MP3s into an existing structure or add folders if needed
    rem example of MP3-file pattern: Wu-Tang Clan - Gravel Pit (LP Version Clean).mp3

    SETLOCAL

    rem set variables
    SET "source=g:\music\folder"
    SET "str=Wu-Tang Clan - Gravel Pit (LP Version Clean).mp3"
    SET "test=%source%\%str%"

    rem split the filename from the remaining path. Take the left part
    rem and assign it to %band% while the right part gets assigned to %song%
    FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ("%test%") DO SET "result=%%~nxi"

    SET "band=%result: - =" & SET "song=%"

    rem If there is no such folder (%band%), create it
    IF not exist "%source%\%band%" MD "%source%\%band%"

    rem As soon as there definetely is a fitting folder
    rem move the file over there.
    MOVE /-Y "%source%\%result%" "%source%\%band%"
```

The next step would be to enhance the code by a for-loop so I don't have to edit the script for every single one of my 3k+ files ;)

I tried really hard to get this code going, but failed:
        @echo off
        SETLOCAL

```
    SET "source=g:\music\folder"

    FOR %%f IN (%source%\*.mp3) DO (
    echo %%f

    FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ("%%f") DO SET "result=%%~nxi"

    SET "band=!result: - =" & SET "song=%"

    IF not exist "%source%\%band%" MD "%source%\%band%"

    MOVE /-Y "%source%\%result%" "%source%\%band%"
    )
    pause
```

So I added a for-loop and %%f was correctly filled at first and wasn't in the next for-loop.

```
    FOR %%f IN (%source%\*.mp3) DO (
    echo %%f
```

That resulted in: "g:\music\folder\Wu-Tang Clan - Gravel Pit (LP Version Clean).mp3"

Like it was supposed to. But after that

```
    FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ("%%f") DO SET "result=%%~nxi"
```

result and every following variable was empty, always.

I tried to fix it with a second variable as a 'helper':

```
    FOR %%f IN (%source%\*.mp3) DO (
    SET "helper=%%f"
    FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ("%helper%") DO SET "result=%%~nxi"
```

Even added 'enabledelayedexpansion' after I read about that and went for

```
    FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ("!helper!") DO SET "result=%%~nxi"
```

still doesn't work.

Now I could really need some help and would really appreciate it :)

regards Phoenix

Comment: You will need [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/5047996) to put your code in a `for` loop and use the `!variable!` expansion syntax; otherwise, when stating `%variable%`, it will expand to the value present _before_ the entire loop executes;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next code snippet could work. Note that the `SET "band=%result: - =" & SET "song=%"` trick can't be performed using  `!` delayed expansion unlike `%`-expansion. Therefore, that command is moved to the `:myset` subroutine and executed via [`call` command](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html).

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "source=g:\music\folder"
FOR %%f IN (%source%\*.mp3) DO (
  echo %%f
  FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ("%%f") DO SET "result=%%~nxi"
  call :myset
  IF not exist "%source%\!band!" MD "%source%\!band!"
  MOVE /-Y "%source%\!result!" "%source%\!band!"
)
goto :skipMyset

:myset
  SET "band=%result: - =" & SET "song=%"
goto :eof

:skipMyset
pause
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: A SUBROUTINE!!!! Of course -.- Now it does its job. Thanks a lot JosefZ for fast and correct answer, made my day :)