# Find a string containing a substring in windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a textfile (`filename.txt`) which contains

```
ProductABC_Test.txt
ProductDEF_Test.txt
ProductHIG_Test.txt
ProductIJK_Test.txt
```

I will be getting a variable passed (ex: product=ABC which will be substring of ProductABC_Test.txt). So I need to fetch the correct test name (ProductABC_Test.txt) from the filename.txt.

I have tried the following code -

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
@echo off
set product=ABC
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (filename.txt) do 
(
    set str=%%A
    if NOT %str% == !%str:product=% 
    (
        set test_suite=%%A
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
echo %test_suite%
```

But I am not getting the right result.

Comment: You need [Delayed Variable Expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/5047996) because you are setting _and_ reading a variable within a block of code, so `!str!` rather than `%str%`, and also `!str:%product%=!`...

Comment: @aschipfl - your points look great. Now I understand about the Delayed Variable Expansion. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please note that `DOS` is an Operating System from the 80s/90s! Please use the tag Windows instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to look for the line that contains your substring:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set product=ABC
set test_suite="not found"
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (filename.txt) do (
    set str=%%A
    Echo.!str! | findstr /C:"!product!">nul
    if !errorlevel!==0 set test_suite=!str!
)
echo %test_suite%
pause
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dennis. You given exactly what I need.