# Windows Batch: findstr not setting ERRORLEVEL within a for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10, command-prompt

Can anyone explain to me why the following snippet prints `0`:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f %%i in ('cmd /c echo blah') do (
    echo %%i | findstr bin > NUL
    echo %ERRORLEVEL%
)
```

While adding another, equivalent statement outside of the for-loop makes it print `1 1`:

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo blah | findstr bin > NUL
echo %ERRORLEVEL%

for /f %%i in ('cmd /c echo blah') do (
    echo %%i | findstr bin > NUL
    echo %ERRORLEVEL%
)
```

I'm a bit of a newbie to Batch, so this is kinda mysterious to me since the two statements seem to be unrelated. Any help with this would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file. Try: `echo  !ERRORLEVEL!`; this is [delayed expansion](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060823-00/?p=29993). You can enable it by: `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that within a `code block` (parenthesised series of statements) any `%var%`will be replaced by the actual value of the variable at `parse time`.

Hin your first example, `%errorlevel%` `0` and echoed as such. In second example, it is `1` when the `for` is encountered, hence it it replaced by `1`.

If you want to display a value of an environment variable that may be changed within a loop, then you need to do one of three things:

1. Invoke `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and echo `!var!` instead of `%var%` - noting that the number of nested `setlocal` instructions you can have active is limited.
2. Call a subroutine
3. Employ a syntax-exploit.

There are many, many articles about `delayedexpansion` on SO.

Crudely, you could simply use (note - case is largely irrelevant in batch, except for the case of the loop-control variable (`metavariable` - `%%i` in this instance)

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

echo blah | findstr bin > NUL
echo %ERRORLEVEL% or !errorlevel!

for /f %%i in ('cmd /c echo blah') do (
    echo %%i | findstr bin > NUL
    echo %ERRORLEVEL% or !errorlevel!
)
```

Another way is to dynamically invoke `setlocal`

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo blah | findstr bin > NUL
echo %ERRORLEVEL% or !errorlevel!
for /f %%i in ('cmd /c echo blah') do (
    echo %%i | findstr bin > NUL
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    echo %ERRORLEVEL% or !errorlevel!
    endlocal    
)
```

The disadvantage of this is that the `endlocal` backs out any changes made to the environment since that last `setlocal`. Also note that if `delayedexpansion` is not in effect, `!` is no longer a special character.

Or, you can use `errorlevel` in its traditional manner:

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo blah | findstr bin > NUL
echo %ERRORLEVEL% or !errorlevel!

for /f %%i in ('cmd /c echo blah') do (
    echo %%i | findstr bin > NUL
    if errorlevel 1 (echo errorlevel is 1 or greater
    ) else (echo errorlevel is 0
    )
)
```

Note that this looks at the `run-time` value of `errorlevel` and `if errorlevel n` means "if errorlevel is n **or greater than n**"

Or - call a subroutine:

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo blah | findstr bin > NUL
echo %ERRORLEVEL% or !errorlevel!
for /f %%i in ('cmd /c echo blah') do (
    echo %%i | findstr bin > NUL
    call :show
)
goto :eof

:show
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
goto :eof
```

Note here that `goto :eof` (here the colon is important - this means "go to the physical end-of-file"

Or, a special version of using a subroutine - a syntax-exploit

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo blah | findstr bin > NUL
echo %ERRORLEVEL% or !errorlevel!
for /f %%i in ('cmd /c echo blah') do (
    echo %%i | findstr bin > NUL
    call echo %%errorlevel%%
)
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about the syntax exploit. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @DavidPostill: I've not seen any official documentation - OTOH, I've not looked for it either. It works by using the parsing system where `%` escapes `%` so when performing a `call`, the remainder of the line is resolved to `echo %varname%`. Same comment can be made about `call set var=%%var2%%` to `set` a variable indirectly.

Comment: Thanks. Looks easier than using delayedexpansion for some cases ;)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

If you put your `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` statement after the closing `)` of the for statement it works as expected.

```
for /f %%i in ('cmd /c echo blah') do (
    echo %%i | findstr bin > NUL
)
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

I'm kind of guessing here, for the exact 'definitive' reason, but `setlocal` is definitely causing it. I'm assuming the value of the ERRORLEVEL within the for loop is the result of the `cmd /c ...` statement. It seems like a strange behavior, but I've seen worse in batch files.

If you remove the `setlocal` at the beginning it works as one would normally expect it to..

ORIGINAL:

The `findstr` sets the `errorlevel` when it runs. So, `echo %errorlevel%` will always output 0.

For example the following findstr statement is successful, so it outputs the line with the match (the only line passed to it):

```
C:\>echo blahbin | findstr bin
blahbin
C:\>echo %errorlevel%
0            ; success / found it..
```

While this statement is not successful (findstr doesn't output anything) and the errorlevel is set to 1:

```
C:\>echo blah_in | findstr bin
C:\>echo %errorlevel%
1            ; failed
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. That's not the problem though, the problem is that it's outputting `0` (in the first part of my question) when it should be outputting `1`.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that.. Just a sec.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f %%i in ('cmd /c echo blah') do (
    echo %%i | findstr bin > NUL
    echo !ERRORLEVEL!
)
```

this should work.

A for loop in cmd is technically one line, so the variable gets expanded only once. Using exclamation marks instead of percent and "ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION" should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:::This part is not exactly necessary but it creates the file dictionary.txt and the var - this
echo.word>dictionary.txt
set this=notaword

:::So instead of checking for errorlevel just check for a space in the output
:middle
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr /n /b /c:%this% dictionary.txt') do (
  set "output=%%a"
  goto :yeah
)
:yeah
if exist %output% (""," "
    goto :oops
) else (
    goto :nice
)
:oops
echo.%this% is NOT a word
pause & set this=word & goto :middle
:nice
echo.%output%
pause
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation?

Comment: So I have been struggling with for loops and the errorlevel problem - Where the errorlevel of the for loop overides the errorlevel of the FINDSTR output. Above is my solution to the problem. This uses the ' IF EXIST ' statement to capture return ("") and spaces (" ") and if they are found it will go to the :oops subroutine. If not then then the word was found and it goes to :nice