# Batch FOR /D outputs unusable values?

Tags: loops, batch-file

When I run this in a batch file:

```
for /d %%i in ("%SystemDrive%\Users\*") do (
  set myvar=%%i\apple
  set myvar=%myvar%\orange
)
```

My output looks like this:

```
set myvar=C:\Users\Joe\apple
 set myvar=\orange

set myvar=C:\Users\Bob\apple
 set myvar=\orange

...
```

I'm expecting to see `set myvar=C:\Users\Joe\apple\orange`.  Why does `myvar` appear to be have an empty value even though you can see it being set with one?

Comment: This is the classic delayed expansion problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file.

Comment: @bgoldst I tried adding `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` but that didn't help.  What would the batch file need to look like to output what I'm expecting?

Comment: You also must use exclamation marks on delayed expansions, rather than percents. So the second assignment must be changed to `set myvar=!myvar!\orange`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, this generates the expected result:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /d %%i in ("%SystemDrive%\Users\*") do (
  set myvar=%%i\apple
  set myvar=!myvar!\orange
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `call`.  For example:

```
for /d %%i in ("%SystemDrive%\Users\*") do call :MyFunction
exit
:MyFunction
set myvar=%%i\apple
set myvar=%myvar%\orange
```