# List directory and numerate it for text based menu

Tags: batch-file, text, menu

I got a problem,
Im trying to make a numerated list of a directory and its containing folders for a text based menu. Main Problem is, that i want them to be numerated. for example:

1:Folder A

2:Folder B

3:Folder C

my idea was to write the directory and its containing folders in a seperate file and read the lines after each other adding a variable in front which increases each line. sadly it does not work. All i get is:

0:Folder A

0:Folder B

0:Folder C

```
    @echo off
dir "directory" /a:d /b > tmp.txt
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (tmp.txt) do (
    set /a N+=1
    echo %N%:%%a
)
```

regards

Comment: Related: [Example of delayed expansion in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I actually got the soloution with the help of this link
[Example of delayed expansion in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file/10558905#10558905)

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set COUNT=0
dir "directory" /a:d /b > tmp.txt  
  for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (tmp.txt) do (
    set /A COUNT=!COUNT! + 1
    ECHO !COUNT!:%%a
  )
```