# Why variable doesn't work inside for /F command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

If you have a variable inside this `for /f` command, it doesn't get printed out to file.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%i in ('dir /B') do (
    set duration=asdf
    echo %duration% > file.txt
)
```

Contents of `file.txt`: `Echo is ON.`

If you move `set duration=asdf` out of `for /f` wrap and put it below `setlocal` line it works correct and prints `asdf` into `file.txt`

Why? How do I do this with the set variable inside the `for` command?

Comment: You enabled [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) but you are not using it; replace `%duration%` by `!duration!` to actually use it...

Comment: Despite duration not being set by the loop, there is no need to set anything, you would just echo %%i.

Comment: You were shown how to use Delayed Expansion in your previous question. What didn't you understand about it in your previous question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file), which stops variables from being *set* and *used*, in the same command.

You are getting `Echo is ON.` in `file.txt`, because to the command interpreter it's reading the `echo` command as:

```
echo > file.txt
```

Which as documented by `echo /?`

> Type ECHO without parameters to display the current echo setting.

The simplest fix is to replace the `%` with `!`

**Updated script:**

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%i in ('dir /B') do (
    set duration=asdf
    echo !duration! > file.txt
)
```