# Windows batch: variables set inside a loop are ignored

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I'm using the following code inside a Windows batch (*.bat) file to run several SQL queries:

```
set PSTR=QUERY1,QUERY2

for %%a in (%PSTR%) do (

  set START=%date%:%time%
  "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe" -f "D:\SQL\%%a.sql" -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres db_tom
  set END=%date%:%time%
  echo %%a  DEB %DEB%  FIN %FIN% >> "D:\LOGS\log.txt"
```

The echo writes the following string inside the `log.txt` file:

```
QUERY1 START END
QUERY2 START END
```

The variables set inside the loop are ignored. Is there another way to write this batch in order to get start and end datetime written down?

Comment: Use delayed expansion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in ...(
 set start=!date!:!time!
 ...
 set end=!date!:!time!
 echo !start! !end!
)
```

please consult any of the hundreds of SO items about `delayed expansion` - the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` invokes a mode where `!var!` retrieves the run-time value not the parse-time value of the variable.