# Variable not Echoing in For Loop

Tags: batch-file, variables, for-loop, echo

I am trying to get the file names using a batch file from a folder but it just doesn't work.

I followed guidelines from [here](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) but for some reason this isn't returning anything at all when it should!

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b C:\Users\Desktop\UPD\*.txt') DO SET result=%%G
```

I also tried:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN (dir /b C:\Users\Desktop\UPD\*.txt') DO SET _result=%%~G

echo %_result% >> %~dp0Outputfile.txt
```

What I get is:

```
ECHO is on.
```

**EDIT**

Here is what I did so far now:

```
IF EXIST C:\Users\Nathanael\Desktop\UPD\*.txt (
    echo file found >> %~dp0Outputfile.txt
    chDIR C:\Users\Nathanael\Desktop\UPD\
    dir *.txt /b >> %~dp0Outputfile.txt

    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b C:\Users\Nathanael\Desktop\UPD\*.txt') DO SET result=%%G
    echo %result% >> %~dp0Outputfile.txt
)
```

The output is:

```
file found
NewVHD.txt
random.txt
ECHO is on.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example of delayed expansion in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file)

Comment: The 'result' is already output as a metavariable, `%G`, so your post would not have an issue were you to use that metavariable within the loop instead of setting it first to a local variable and using that, `For /F %%G IN ("C:\Users\Nathanael\Desktop\UPD\*.txt") Do (Echo %%G)>>"%~dp0OutputFile"`. But you're not really just echoing to a file, are you? because you already know that, `Dir /B "C:\Users\Nathanael\Desktop\UPD\*.txt">"%~dp0OutputFile"` can do that. It would be much better were you to show us what you're intending to do with `%result%` so that solutions can be tailored accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If the `for /f` returns multiple files the last one will overwrite the previous in the `set`
- The way cmd.exe parses (code blocks) requires delayed expansion when a var is set and used inside the same code block as is the case with your `if exist`

So either avoid the code block with reversed logic

```
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Users\Nathanael\Desktop\UPD\*.txt" Goto :Eof or other label
```

Or (always indent code blocks to better keep track) :

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
IF EXIST "C:\Users\Nathanael\Desktop\UPD\*.txt" (
    echo file found >> %~dp0Outputfile.txt
    chDIR "C:\Users\Nathanael\Desktop\UPD\"
    dir "*.txt" /b >> %~dp0Outputfile.txt
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b C:\Users\Nathanael\Desktop\UPD\*.txt') DO SET result=%%G
echo(!result! >> %~dp0Outputfile.txt
)
```

- It's a good habit to always enclose pathes in double quotes
- to avoid `echo is off` messages use an other command separator than a space if the var is possibly empty (I used a `(` here

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b C:\Users\Desktop\UPD*.txt') DO SET result=%%G
```

Make sure that the path is correct (for example, perhaps it should be `c:\Users\YourName\Desktop\UPD*.txt` where `YourName` is the user name)?

Comment: Thanks for the replied, I noticed all of that after posting :S. 
Did the changes and still the same results

Comment: I saw your fix to _result so I removed that part of my answer.  Try running the `dir` command from the command line to make sure that it returns the expected value.

Comment: IF EXIST C:\Users\Nathanael\Desktop\UPD\*.txt (
 echo file found >> %~dp0Outputfile.txt
 chDIR C:\Users\Nathanael\Desktop\UPD\
 dir *.txt /b >> %~dp0Outputfile.txt

 FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b C:\Users\Nathanael\Desktop\UPD\*.txt') DO SET result=%%G
 echo %result% >> %~dp0Outputfile.txt
 )

The output:
CheckVHD started 
nathan 
file found 
NewVHD.txt
random.txt