# Why does %CD% not work in a for loop with PushD

Tags: loops, batch-file, pushd

I want to run a .bat script which makes a file and save it with the same name as the folder it is in. I want it to start in a map and loop through the submaps.
I started with this code below and run it in one of the submaps. That works, I get a file with the name of the submap.

```
FOR /D %%I IN ("%CD%") DO SET _LAST_SEGMENT_=%%~nxI
ECHO Last segment = "%_LAST_SEGMENT_%"
echo.>%_LAST_SEGMENT_%.mp4
pause
```

So now I only have to place it in a for loop. So I made the code below, which is not working. It seems that the `%CD%` is referring to my parent map(subfolders), where the `.bat` file is located, instead of my submaps (video1, video2, etc.).

```
Set Base=C:\Video\subfolders
FOR /R "%Base%" %%F IN (.) DO (
    PushD "%%F"
        FOR /D %%I IN ("%CD%") DO SET _LAST_SEGMENT_=%%~nxI
        echo %CD%
        ECHO Last segment = "%_LAST_SEGMENT_%"
        echo.>%_LAST_SEGMENT_%.mp4
    PopD
)
Pause
```

Output:

```
C:\Video\subfolders>Set Base=C:\Video\subfolders
C:\Video\subfolders>FOR /R "C:\Video\subfolders" %F IN (.) DO (
PushD "%F"
 FOR / %I IN ("C:\Video\subfolders") DO SET _LAST_SEGMENT_=%~nxI
 echo C:\Video\subfolders
 ECHO Last segment = ""
 echo.   1>.mp4
 PopD
)
C:\Video\subfolders>(
PushD "C:\Video\subfolders\."
 FOR / %I IN ("C:\Video\subfolders") DO SET _LAST_SEGMENT_=%~nxI
 echo C:\Video\subfolders
 ECHO Last segment = ""
 echo.   1>.mp4
 PopD
)
C:\Video\subfolders>SET _LAST_SEGMENT_=subfolders
C:\Video\subfolders
Last segment = ""
C:\Video\subfolders>(
PushD "C:\Video\subfolders\video1\."
 FOR / %I IN ("C:\Video\subfolders") DO SET _LAST_SEGMENT_=%~nxI
 echo C:\Video\subfolders
 ECHO Last segment = ""
 echo.   1>.mp4
 PopD
)
C:\Video\subfolders\video1>SET _LAST_SEGMENT_=subfolders
C:\Video\subfolders
Last segment = ""
C:\Video\subfolders>(
PushD "C:\Video\subfolders\video2\."
 FOR / %I IN ("C:\Video\subfolders") DO SET _LAST_SEGMENT_=%~nxI
 echo C:\Video\subfolders
 ECHO Last segment = ""
 echo.   1>.mp4
 PopD
)
C:\Video\subfolders\video2>SET _LAST_SEGMENT_=subfolders
C:\Video\subfolders
Last segment = ""
C:\Video\subfolders>(
PushD "C:\Video\subfolders\video3\."
 FOR / %I IN ("C:\Video\subfolders") DO SET _LAST_SEGMENT_=%~nxI
 echo C:\Video\subfolders
 ECHO Last segment = ""
 echo.   1>.mp4
 PopD
)
C:\Video\subfolders\video3>SET _LAST_SEGMENT_=subfolders
C:\Video\subfolders
Last segment = ""
C:\Video\subfolders>Pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I saw the link below which explain to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` but I can’t get this to work.

https://superuser.com/questions/503488/why-doesnt-cd-work-after-using-pushd-to-a-unc-path

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want something like:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\Video\subfolders\*" /AD-H /B /S 2^>nul') do (
    pushd "%%I"
    echo/>"%%~nxI.mp4"
    popd
)
```

The commands `pushd` and `popd` are not really necessary as demonstrated with below code:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\Video\subfolders\*" /AD-H /B /S 2^>nul') do (
    echo Directory is: %%I
    echo/>"%%I\%%~nxI.mp4"
)
```

The command **FOR** runs in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background the command line:

```
dir "C:\Video\subfolders\*" /AD-H /B /S 2>nul
```

The command **DIR** outputs to handle **STDOUT** of this background command process

- in bare format because of option `/B`  just all names with full path because of option `/S`
- of non-hidden directories because of option `/AD-H` (attribute directory and not hidden)
- in specified directory `C:\Video\subfolders` and all its subdirectories.

The error message output by **DIR** to handle **STDERR** on not finding any directory entry in entire directory tree of `C:\Video\subfolders` is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures the output to **STDOUT** of started command process and processes this output line by line with ignoring empty lines and by default also lines starting with a semicolon which both do not occur here.

**FOR** would also split up every line into substrings on spaces/tabs and would assign just first space/tab separated string to specified loop variable `I`. Directory names can have spaces and for that reason `delims=` is used to define an empty list of string delimiters resulting in getting assigned to loop variable `I` always the entire full qualified directory name currently processed from captured **DIR** output.

The name of the directory without path is referenced with `%%~nxI` which is the string after last backslash. A directory name can contain also a dot like `folder.name` or start with a dot like `.FolderName` although both are unusual on Windows. For that reason it is necessary to use `%%~nxI` (name and extension) and not just `%%~nI` because of **FOR** does not verify if string referenced with `%%I` is a file or directory name.

`%%~nI` references the string **between** last `\` (or `/` for compatibility with Linux paths replaced all first by `\`) if there is any backslash (or slash) at all **or** beginning of string if there is no `\` (or `/`) **and** last dot if there is a `.` at all after already determined beginning of name string **or** end of string if there is no dot. `%%~xI` references the string beginning with last dot found after last directory separator. So the string assigned to loop variable `I` must not be a file/folder name of a really existing file/folder although this is the case here. `%%~nxI` would be an empty string if `I` holds a string ending with `\` (or `/`).

Do not assign a string which can be referenced using a loop variable without or with a modifier to an environment variable as this would require the usage of [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as explained by help of command **SET** output on running in a command prompt window `set /?`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`

See also DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774).

The second batch file code in question does not work because of not using delayed expansion or avoiding the usage of environment variables defined/modified inside a command block and referenced within same command block using syntax `%variable%`. The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` parses the entire command block from `(`  of first **FOR** to matching `)` before executing the outer **FOR** the first time. See [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/) All `%variable%` references within this command block are replaced during this preprocessing phase already by current value of the referenced environment variable. So the code finally executed on iterating outer **FOR** does not contain anymore any `%variable%` environment variable reference as it can be seen on command lines output by `cmd.exe` before executing the command line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and extensive explanation! The second piece of code worked exactly as i needed. And by the explanation I now know what it does as well.

Answer (score 1):

While [Mofi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53636915/567650) resolved OP's issue, it doesn't actually answer the question originally asked.

The reason `%CD%` doesn't work inside a `FOR` loop is that you need to enable "[delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)"

For example:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%i in (foo bar) DO (
    pushd %%i
    echo CD with delayed expansion: !CD!
    echo CD without it: %CD%
)
```

Assuming the "foo" and "bar" directories exist when you run that, you should see that `!CD!` gives the correct path.

More examples: [Example of delayed expansion in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file)