# Batch Unable to set variable in for loop

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%i IN (1,1,5) do (
    set /A is_echoing=0
    if %%i==2 (set /A is_echoing=1)
    if %%i==5 (set /A is_echoing=1)
    if %is_echoing%==1 (
        echo Hello World
    )
)
endlocal
```

It is giving me an error:

```
( was unexpected at this time
                    if ==1 (
```

It seems the variable is_echoing is not set in the for loop. Why is this the case and what can I do about it?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/62576) for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I have included setlocal enabledelayedexpansion, so that is not the issue.

Comment: But you're not using it, because you're still using `%%i` inside the loop. Read it again. :-)

Comment: Hmm, not sure I get it after reading the 5th time, so I should use !!i instead?

Comment: The second code block in that answer demonstrates the proper use of `!`. In your case, it would be `!i!`.

Comment: Oh I see, I get it now, thanks a lot!