# Assign variables in a FOR loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to process all files in a directory, eg. replace the extension and rename the file. The problem is, I cannot move the filename into a variable (seems to be a problem with the scope of variables).

Here is what I have coded:

```
@echo off
cls

setlocal
set myname=hugo
echo myname=%myname%

::process all files in directory
for %%f in (C:\windows\*.ico) do (
   echo F=%%f                <--- this works fine
   set myname=%%f            <--- this does NOT work!
   echo.myname=%myname%
)
echo myname=%myname%         <--- displays last set
endlocal
```

And this is the output:

```
myname=hugo
F=C:\windows\AnyWeb Print.ico
myname=hugo
F=C:\windows\Dr. Printer Icon.ico
myname=hugo
F=C:\windows\SmartCMS2.ico
myname=hugo
myname=C:\windows\SmartCMS2.ico
```

I cannot modify the variable "myname" within he loop, but once the loop has ended, it contains the value, that I have tried to assign most recently.

Obviously I don't understand the way a batch file handles variables in a FOR loop. I seem to lack some info about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example of delayed expansion in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file) or [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected). I can assure you the `set` command does work, but it is the expansion of `%myname%` that is failing…

Comment: This is my coding now:

::process all files in directory
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%f in (C:\windows\*.ico) do (

   echo F=%%f
   set myname=%%f
   echo.N=!myname!
   call :strlen myLen "!myname!"
   echo.myLen=!myLen!

   set /A L=myLen-3 + 1
   set str=!myname!
   echo.str1=!str! L=!L!
   set str=!str:~0,!L! !
   echo.str2=!str!

)

Here is the output of my call :

F=C:\windows\AnyWeb Print.ico
N=C:\windows\AnyWeb Print.ico
Strlen C:\windows\AnyWeb Print.ico
myLen=25
str1=C:\windows\AnyWeb Print.ico L=23
str2=L       <--- what went wrong ????

Answer (score 0):

The expansion of variables inside `FOR` loops requires you to ***enable delayed expansion*** to force variables to be expanded at runtime instead of being expanded when parsed. Read `HELP SET` for more information.

And try changing your code to

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (C:\windows\*.ico) do (
   set myname=%%f
   echo !myname!;
)
```

Note that the variable is referenced with an slightly different syntax `!myname!` instead of `%myname%`. *Delayed environment variable expansion allows you to use a different character (the exclamation mark) to expand environment variables at execution time.*